# Can't get RubyGems to install Maven artifacts using JRuby

Tags: ruby, maven, rubygems, jruby, maven-3

We're porting a legacy Java app to JRuby and would like to reuse some Maven JARs we do not plan to port to Ruby (this is actually the reason we chose JRuby instead of MRI).

I googled and found that RubyGems shipped with JRuby has built-in support for Maven dependencies handling, but I can't get RubyGems to resolve them.

I tried `gem install joda-time:joda-time`, `gem install mvn:commons-lang:commons-lang`, `jgem install mvn:commons-lang:commons-lang` and `jruby -S gem install mvn:commons-lang:commons-lang`:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'mvn:commons-lang:commons-lang' (>= 0) in any repository
```

We use JRuby 1.6.7 installed by RVM :

```
$ ruby --version
jruby 1.6.7 (ruby-1.8.7-p357) (2012-02-22 3e82bc8) (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_26) [linux-amd64-java]
```

How could we have RubyGems handle Maven artifacts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to resolve Maven dependencies using Bundler / [JBundler](https://github.com/mkristian/jbundler).